# Spring beans usage inside library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I'm developing some libs for internal use in my company, which using spring and spring Boot.

I'm encountered a problem with my bean definition. I want to create some beans of objects that don't belong to my library, for example:

```
@Configuration
public class LibClass {
@Bean 
public Gson gson() { return new Gson();}}
```

However, whenever I do this it affect the service that using my library and creating beans for them too, which means they will be forced to use my Gson or enabling overriding of beans, by defining `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` which feels wrong.

For example, if I have the same code as above in my service:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceClass {
@Bean 
public Gson gson() { return new Gson();}}
```

Spring throws

> BeanDefinitionOverrideException

1. Is creating those kind of beans inside a library is a good practice?
2. How can I tell spring to use this bean just inside my libraries classes and not outside

Thanks

Edit:
As I mentioned in the comments, I don't want to force using of @Qualifier, as if they don't using it already, which we don't if there is no need to, they will get this exception and won't know why as it is not trivial to understand that some libraries using random beans. Nonetheless, if someone forget to create a bean, they can use the lib bean, by mistake, without even knowing. This could cause some nasty and unexpected behavior.
Also, the annotation @ConditionalOnMissingBean won't help me here, as I won't be able to configure specific configuration later if needed and my internal library will be affected by an unknown configuration from the user, which isn't seem like a good practice

Comment: Why not just limit the access modifier for that bean or the class to be package private, or even private if possible?

Comment: According to the knowledge i have Spring initialize beans at startup might be you are defining beans with similar name adding different name in @Bean("ABC) annotation will fix your problem if this is the case

Comment: might be a code will help understanding more

Comment: @Jason I'm we are using configurations inside configuration package. Also, I want all classes inside my library to have access to this bean

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I don't want to force people using my library using Qualifier, it is an opening for trouble, because if someone will be using Gson, for example, and forgot to declare it, he will be using my lib definition without knowing, which can cause some nasty issues. Also, I updated my question, I hope that it is more insightful now

Comment: The problem, regardless of using qualifiers or not, is that your bean will influence the application of the user. If you don't want that you must repackage your dependencies and put them in a different namespace/package (like Spring does with ASM, CGLib and some other dependencies). That way you can use GSON or your version of GSON without influencing the users library. Else just use an `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` which will only create the bean when it isn't defined already.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm not familiar with the idea of different namespaces/packages, I'll read about this and check if it can help me. About ConditionalOnMissingBean, if the library is loaded before the service, which in my case is needed, It won't help me

Comment: @M.Deinum also, if you have any good guide or documentations about the concept of different namespaces/packages, I'll be glad if you can share it with me, thanks:)

Comment: The configuration is loaded all at the same time so that doesn't make sense. About the different packages check for repackaging a dependency into your own library (or check Spring how they include asm, cglib and objenisis.

Comment: @M.Deinum not if you are using @DependsOn(), which is my case

Comment: It is... The configuration is still loaded on the same time. The `@DependsOn` doesn't change that, that might onlyu change the order in which beans are loaded. Again nothing preventing you from using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`.

Comment: @M.Deinum actually you are right, I checked this again and it work, I must have somehow messed up the last time I had tried it... This is nice, but it still not exactly solve my problem, because if I'll ever need to pass Gson some configurations for my lib, I won't be able to do so. Also, my internal library will be effected by unknown configuration, and I don't think that it is a good practice

Answer (score 2):

changing the bean name and adding a qualifier should work:

```
@Bean 
@Qualifier("gsonForInternal")
public Gson gsonForInternal() { return new Gson();}
```

where autowiring you should :

```
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("gsonForInternal")
private Gson gsonForInternal;
```

Edit:
in case you want you can make this bean conditional:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@Bean 
public Gson gson() { return new Gson();}
```

however if the library user will define its own bean:

```
@Bean 
public Gson gson() { return new Gson();}
```

this means your library will use his defined `Gson`

so i think you should be using qualifier - if i understand your requirement correctly

Comment: I don't want to force people using my library to use @Qualifier as if they will forget to define Gson for themselves, and won't use qualifier they will be using mine without knowing, which may cause some nasty and hard to detect exceptions

Comment: i thought you only wanted this Gson bean to be exposed inside your library , not for your library users , you could use @Conditional if this is what you want

Comment: I had updated my question to be more clear. Conditional is not good enough, as I have @DependsOn() to load the lib first (the library is loading environment variables from zookeeper, which I need to have before I'm loading the service beans)

Comment: so to make sure i understand :
1. you load your library.
2.you load the service library.

your library is using gson and the service library is using Gson , what would you want the scope of the Gson bean to have  exactly ? , you wrote "you dont want to force people using your library to use qualifiers" - but i guess you are exposing other bean that is relevant to your library - if so why would the users of your library care that you are using a qualifier for a bean which you should only use internally ?

Comment: 2. I load the service configurations, not library. My lib use Gson, that could be initialized with some custom configuration. The service also need Gson, but he can have different custom configuration then my library. The Gson inside my library is for the library use only, the service shouldn't use it otherwise. The Gson in my service should used by the service and not by my library. They are different objects. If I use a qualifier, if you, as a user, will try to use Gson without any qualifier, you will get my Gson as it is the only existing bean of Gson objects, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: so in the mentioned case you want the user to get the service Gson ?
so why wouldnt creating a qualified Gson for the library and a seperate Gson for the service (without qualifer ) work ?